# PDFLatex producing absurdly large pdf when using axessibility package

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, arxiv

If I compile the main.tex using overleaf and the latex files compile to a 6mb pdf. I use the same engine to compile the pdf on local machine using pdflatex and I get 140mb pdf file. The problem happens only when using the package:
`\usepackage[accsupp]{axessibility}`

**But the problem happens only locally with the above package and not on overleaf**

The source files and assets (like images) combined are just a few mbs. I am having a hard time understanding where the issue is.

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14128 strings out of 481239
 231003 string characters out of 5920377
 544979 words of memory out of 5000000
 28581 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 589840 words of font info for 350 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 49i,12n,46p,1246b,525s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/share/texliv
e/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbsy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/font
s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi5.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmmi9.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb
></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/s
hare/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/share/tex
live/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></usr/share/texlive/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy9.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/u
rw/courier/ucrr8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb
8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmbi8a.pfb></usr/s
hare/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (18 pages, 149582541 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 624 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 502 compressed objects within 6 object streams
 127 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 39728 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 42996 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Looks like you're embedding fonts, maybe, and lots of them? But impossible to tell without knowing your code.

Comment: are the fonts the reason for the really large file size?

Comment: They could easily be if you embed them, yes. When you check the PDF's properties in your PDF reader, what does it say?

Comment: Without knowing more and seeing a minimal working example _including_ an example for the graphic files, it is difficult to guess. But maybe there is a process which converts your image files "on the fly". What kind of image files are embedded? The idea that embedded fonts were the reason of a 140 MB file doesn't seem very probable, at least to me.

Comment: I will try to get a minimal example working but this is the source: 
https://arxiv.org/format/2203.08080

Comment: the source code on arxiv loads `\usepackage[accsupp]{axessibility}` and that creates an uncompressed pdf. Who ever added that has obviously no real idea what the package does and that it is quite experimental.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was the culprit. Thanks so much. It was required for the camera ready version by the conference chairs.

Comment: Likely Overleaf has modified the structure of the package to set the `\pdfcompresslevel=1` which produces a compressed version of the pdf. arXiv has not customized the behavior of this package in any way, so it follows the default when that option is provided.

I did [reach out to the package maintainers](https://github.com/integr-abile/axessibility/issues/20) regarding this condition, but it's unclear if there will be any action on their part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code on arxiv loads `\usepackage[accsupp]{axessibility}` and that package forces the creation of an uncompressed pdf.

The package is quite quite experimental and should be used only with great care.

Answer (score 2):

Likely Overleaf has modified the structure of the package to set the `\pdfcompresslevel=1` which produces a compressed version of the pdf. arXiv has not customized the behavior of this package in any way, so it follows the default when that option is provided. arXiv staff did reach out to the package's maintainers but it'd be up to them to change that behavior in their code.